# SFML White Window

Tags: c++, sfml

For some odd reason my SFML program won't render anything until I mouse over it, or press a key or do anything that qualifies as an event.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you mouse over, this causes a message to be sent to the application. So probably you have your main loop written incorrectly, so that it won't render until a message is received. But this is a random guess, you should consider always posting your code together with your question.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I had my drawing stuff in the event loop; so therefore it was only drawing when an event happened. Thanks though.